# Why is variable assignment costing so much time in my value iteration algorithm?

Tags: c++, performance, profiling

I have a routine, posted below with profiling results as comments. The routine gets called a few thousand times. statesVec contains about 1000000 states. When profiling, I note the following:

```
void IterateValues()
{
    for (auto& sw : statesVec)
    {
        sw.oldVal = sw.newval; //43%
    }
    for (auto& sw : statesVec) //6.5%
    {
            auto& probs = mrp.EventProbs();
            auto NumEvents = probs.size();

            sw.newval = sw.CostsInState;//1% !
            for (size_t event = 0; event < NumEvents; event++)
            {
                //Note sw.TransitsToStates is a vector containing 
                //pointers to elements of statesVec
                sw.newval += sw.TransitsToStates[event]->oldVal * probs[event];//49.5%
            }
            sw.newval*=alpha;
     }
}
```

statesVec contains states:

```
 Struct state
 {
   double newval;
   double oldVal;
   std::vector<State*> TransitsToStates;
   double CostsInState;
 }
```

(Not sure if this is important: The code finds the value function of a (very sparse) markov reward process by repeated value iteration. It does this by computing V_{t+1}(s)=\sum_{s' in S} P(s,s') V(s). P(s,s') is very sparse, so I keep a list of pointers to the states that s can transit to for every s (sw.transitstostates[event].)

I want to gain a better understanding of why things certain things are costing time. I am especially concerned about the fact that the first simple assignment takes 43% of the time, even if not a single computation is being made there. In that light, I am also surprised that the first assignment to s.newval (to s.CostsInState) does not take any time according to the profiler (very sleepy). So my question is why these things are the way they are. Am I right in inferring that the fact that the first assignment in the second loop is probably an artifact of the profiler? What causes simple assignment to be so slow compared to actual computations, and even an inner loop? Is there anything that can be done about this?

(It seems that it is possible to refactor the code such that I do two iterations, where oldval and newval switch roles, to avoid this speed bump. But the code will get substantially less readable, so I rather first understand what is going on here. )

Comment: How many values are in `TransitsToStates` for each `state` structure? That could be an issue.

Comment: Also, each loop takes almost 50% of the function, which seems about right. It's not the code inside the loops that takes up the time, it's that you loop over all elements twice.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In the order of 10-20. Note that actually, it seems that it is spending way too much time in the first loop, which doesn't even use the transitstostates..

Comment: You know these numbers always add up to 100, right? What makes you think this is sub-optimal? The time taken by the loop statement is likely because the container is very large and it has a lot of cache misses in lookup by traversing all of them (twice). On the other hand, the assignment in the loop is fast because that element is now in the cache.

Comment: A single load from RAM is ~200 cycles, as opposed to 1..3 cycles for + and * operations. For the most part you can ignore your math ops and only count cache misses, which would give a ~50/50 split in time spent in the two loops you're observing. Try traversing memory in smaller, sequential chunks.

Comment: Where did you expect the time to be spent? What operations do you expect to be more expensive than floating point assignment?

Comment: @JaMiT after reading up on cache misses, I think I now understand the reason that the loops are about equally fast. So computation time is determined by the number of cache misses here, and there will be plenty since the vector is so large. Somehow, I never encountered this in my scientific programming before, probably because I rarely consume so much memory.

Comment: @rustyx Thanks for your suggestion. So this algorithm makes it hard to traverse less memory: Each pass must visit every state. But I am interested by your suggestion to use sequential chunks? I.e. I could have one vector that only contains the newvals, i.e. a vec<double>, and another one containing the old values. How would that help? Why is "sequential" helpfull? (I see how smaller chunks would be helpfull now.